# WinDbg MEM_COMMIT is at 1GB, eeheap is showing 150MB, can't find remaining memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, windbg

I am having a bit of trouble trying to find some unmanaged memory allocation from a .dmp file.

I have been trying to follow the tips - [here](http://kate-butenko.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/investigating-issues-with-unmanaged.html) but I am hitting a bit of a wall

***!address -summary*** gives me the below which shows the MEM_COMMIT is at 1.030Gb which is expected (please ignore the TB of memory, this is probably due to the fact this is from a virtual web server)

[image: Address Summary]

***!eeheap -gc*** gives me the below which shows the .net memory usage is 150MB (if I run ***!eeheap*** on it's own I do not see any extra heaps, I still see 8 GC heaps that total 150MB)

[image: eeheap]

This leads me to believe the majority of the memory usage is coming from unmanaged memory

The instructions I have been following then say to use ***!heap -s*** to find where the unmanaged memory is. When I do that I see the below

[image: heap -s]

Now I would expect to see a large amount of memory being used by a heap that I could further analyse to try and locate the unmanaged memory, but I do not see any heaps that come close to filling showing the 1GB of used memory

I did notice that ***!address -summary*** showed 600MB in PAGE_READWRITE, so I tried **!address /f:PAGE_READWRITE**  which I hoped would give me something else to go on, but it gives me a list of memory used by PAGE_READWRITE and Im not too sure how to analyse any further

Basically I want to know where the difference in memory between 1GB and 150MB of  .net allocated memory is being used

Any help would be great

Comment: The free TB are a result of an application being 64bit. You can get that amount of virtual memory, but it might be swapped to disk.

Comment: load the dmp in DebugDiag analyzer (MemoryAnalysis)

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I haven't managed to get DebugDiag to give me any information about unmanaged memeory

Comment: The only information i get from DebugDiag appears to be from managed memory, the total memory it reports on totals to 150mb

Answer (score 2):

In "Usage Summary", you can see

```
<unknown>  17 GB
Heap       235 MB
```

`<unknown>` can be .NET or memory directly allocated by `VirtualAlloc()`. IMHO, someone using `VirtualAlloc()` directly is quite rare.

`Heap` is memory allocated via the Heap manager. So, `!heap -s` will not show more than 235 MB.

`MEM_COMMIT` is just another state of memory and it can be in any of the usage states. To find the 1 GB of committed memory, you need to sum up everything you have:

```
154 MB used by .NET GC Heaps
235 MB used by Heaps
234 MB used by Images
up to 50 MB in Stacks
... some smaller parts not really relevant
```

This already explains 620 to 670 MB of memory, depending on how much of the stack memory was actually committed.

If you execute `!eeheap` without the `-gc` parameter, you'll see that there is more memory used by .NET since it also has LoaderHeaps, JIT Heaps, domain heaps etc.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify "image" for me? Is it .dll's or actual images?

Comment: @martpendle: Images is the term for DLLs, EXEs and similar. They are loaded into memory to execute code from them and therefore likely 100% committed memory.

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway I can see which ones are loaded and how much memory they are taking up?

Comment: No doubt Windbg can do it to but VMMap from Sysinternals would show that and more quit easily.

Comment: Thanks, if I run !eeheap on its own then I see 8 heaps and the bytes shown there total the same amount of bytes shown under "GC Heap Size". I dont see any other heap types. Am I doing something wrong? (i have added this to my question)

Comment: `lm` lists all images. You can calculate the size from the output. `!lmi <name>` also includes the size. Don't worry too much about images - there's usually not much to optimize.